# No callback for itunes store purchase with different countries store account alert

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am trying to implement in-app purchase for my unity based game.

I have handled almost all the alerts like login, transaction failed and other scenarios. But when I try to initiate a purchase with a test account that is setup for a country other than US, it gives me an alert asking to change accounts with the US iTunes store. When I hit cancel or change store on that alert, I don't get any callback.

Is there any other callback other than SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ios gives failed called back before showing the popup, handled my UI changes there.